# MS SQL week number of month at date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need sql instruction that give me week number of month at date.
Search solution, but no one works as expected.

**First:**

```
 declare @date datetime = '2019-09-01'

 select datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)), 0), @date - 1) + 1
```

Result - 0

```
 declare @date datetime = '2019-09-30'

 select datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)), 0), @date - 1) + 1
```

Result - 5

Check another month - 2019-08-01 (result 1) and 2019-08-31 (result 5)

**Second:**

```
 declare @d datetime = '2019-09-01' 

 select (day(@d)+datepart(weekday,dateadd(day,1-day(@d),@d))-datepart(weekday,@d))/7+1
```

Result - 1

```
 declare @d datetime = '2019-09-30' 

 select (day(@d)+datepart(weekday,dateadd(day,1-day(@d),@d))-datepart(weekday,@d))/7+1
```

Result - 5 (must be 6)

And other solutions that not give result as need.

Problem in first day of week - it's must be monday, not sunday. At september example, need 01 sep - first week, 02 sep - second week and etc

Maybe else instructions?

Comment: Why must it be *6*? The default first day of the week is Sunday. If you want to use a different day, make it explicit in the question.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos add this to question - **Problem in first day of week - it's must be monday, not sunday**

Comment: Oh i think i get it now. Do you want the week no in the month, but with all weeks starting on the same day of the week? Such that the first week of the month could have <7 days in it depending upon the first week day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

September 30, 2019 is in the 5th week, not the sixth, if the default first day of the week is used. That is specified by the [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) setting. This affects date calculations like `DATEADD` and `DATEPART(weekday)`

If you want to use a *different* first day, eg Monday, you'll have to change the setting with

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

When you make that change, your last query works both for `2019-09-01` and `2019-09-30`

```
set datefirst 1

declare @date datetime = '2019-09-30'

select (day(@date)+datepart(weekday,dateadd(day,1-day(@date),@date))- datepart(weekday,@date))/7+1
```

This returns 6. For `2019-01-01` it returns 1

Comment: try add "set datefirst 1" for different instructions, but no work. Try your - all ok. Strange. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you've over complicated it a bit.

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @d datetime = '2019-09-30'

 --Get the day of the month
 DECLARE @DayOfMonth DECIMAL(18,6) = DATEPART(DAY, @d)

 --Divide by 7 (as a decimal) and round up.
 SELECT CEILING(@DayOfMonth / 7.0)
```

Which gives you

```
Day    Week
 1      1
 2      1
 3      1
 4      1
 5      1
 6      1
 7      1
 8      2
 9      2
 10     2
 11     2
 12     2
 13     2
 14     2
 15     3
 16     3
 17     3
 18     3
 19     3
 20     3
 21     3
 22     4
 23     4
 24     4
 25     4
 26     4
 27     4
 28     4
 29     5
 30     5
 31     5
```

Comment: At most a month only has 4.428571 weeks in it. Therefore you can only ever get to week 5. There is never a week 6.

Comment: problem in first day of week - it's must be monday, not sunday. And 01 sep it's for me first week, 02 sep - second

Comment: So are you trying to work out the week day no (starting at 1 for the first day of the month) NOT the week no?

Comment: @SergeySmirnov you should add all that to your question, not force people to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which outputs the number of week in a month for a each date

```
declare @mydate as datetime
declare @thisdate as datetime
declare @month as int
declare @year as int

set @mydate='04/17/2019'

set @month=month(@mydate)
set @year=year(@mydate)
declare @Fmonth as datetime

set @Fmonth=convert(varchar(2),@month) +'/01/'+convert(varchar(4),@year)


declare @mytable as table(mydate datetime)
set @thisdate=@Fmonth
while @thisdate <=EOMONTH (@mydate)
begin
insert into @mytable values(@thisdate)
set @thisdate=dateadd(day,1,@thisdate) 
--print @thisdate
end;



select convert(nvarchar(20),Mydate,103)[Date], row_number() over(partition by [weekend] order by mydate)  [Number_of_week]  from
(select mydate,datepart(w,mydate) [day_of_week] ,case datepart(w,mydate)when 1 then 1 else datepart(w,mydate) end [weekend]from @mytable) v
order by mydate
```

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question? If you propose using a calendar table, you'd still have to calculate the month's week number. That's what the question asks